# Retrieve data by knowing an information in SQL Script

Tags: sql, database

I'm a newbie in SQL and I struggle to solve the following problem:

I have this relational table:

```
Movie (CodMov, Title, ProductionYear, Nationality, Director, Genre)
```

How do I find the "Movie Titles" of all the movies produced by the same director who directed "X", in SQL Script?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a subselect

```
select Title
from Movie 
where Director = ( select Director from Movie
                    where Title = 'X')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select Title 
from Movie 
where Director = (select Director from movie where Title = 'X')
```

Comment: you have a mistake  ... title not titile